# How do I maintain quads and shading after this bevel?

Tags: modeling, mesh, shaders, topology, bevel

I'm trying to keep everything in quads and at the same time maintain a good shading on this mesh.

This is the bevel operation:
[image: Screenshot 1]

Now I know that I can maintain the quads with this method, but unfortunately that way the shading looks really bad as it introduce a bad pole in there:
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]

So I approached this issue another way, this time with separating the vertices by creating new edge loops. However this also didn't solve the shading issue:
[image: Screenshot 4]

What is the most efficient way to keep both topology and shading after beveling operations like this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need some coplanar faces that will prevent the shading between some faces that are not coplanar. To fix it, inset the faces around your bevel:

[image]

Then select the new edge loop here and dissolve with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>:

[image]

Result:

[image]

As Gordon Brinkmann says you don't necessary need quads, but if you use ngons or tris make sure that they are coplanar with their adjacent faces.

Comment: You just solved my issue! I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlivePositive By the way, what moonboots demonstrated to you here is that it is absolutely not necessary to always keep everything quads, especially not when the topology gets more complicated and messy than with using n-gons.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Thank you for your input, I will keep that in mind!

Comment: @AlivePositive Looking at the MatCap you're using this reminds me of Josh Gambrell's tutorials on hard surface modeling. He also has some good videos about why ngons are sometimes better than quads or when to prefer ngons and how to use them reasonably. Just search for "josh gambrell ngon" on Youtube.